# ArchLinux's AUR

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm trying to find more information on the individual AUR ArchLinux packages. When you install a package from the AUR and the package gets updated online, do you get the update when updating via the PacMan, or do you have to update the package on your machine manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use [yaourt](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt) instead of pacman if you want to update your packages including the packages from AUR.

```
yaourt -Syua
```

Answer (score 3):

Another tool I'd recommend for managing AUR packages is **aura**.

You install packages with `aura -Ax` (x isn't necessary but it shows what is going on) and update with `aura -Axyu`. Further information: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Aura

On AUR helpers in general: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers

Answer (score 1):

Packeges from AUR are not updated by 'pacman'. However, there is a package called 'packer' that lets you search AUR just like pacman does the official repositories. This will also let you perform a `packer -Su` which updates all packages on the system, including AUR packages.

You still have to do `pacman -Sy` to update you local database thoug.

Answer (score 1):

No, `pacman` does not update AUR packages for you. No, there are utilities which help you to manage them automatically.

AUR is a repository of building scripts called `PKGBUILD`s, executable by utility `makepkg` (comes with `pacman`) to build binary pacman-packages. `pacman`, on the other hand, is a binary pacman-package management system, which does not read this repository at all.

The traditional and still the recommended way is to monitor `PKGBUILD` updates by yourself (via a script, a firefox plugin or etc.), download the updated `PKGBUILD`, rebuild the updated package with `makepkg`, then reinstall it with `pacman`. Arch Linux officially does not recommend using a automatic system for security reasons.

If you opt for an automatic system such as `yaourt` or `aura`, be sure to take as much care as you manually install the packages. Apart from checking the PKGBUILD online prior to installation, `yaourt` lets you check the `PKGBUILD` before it builds the package by default; `aura` needs `--hotedit` to do so.

Ref: related ArchWiki